# What is the technical way to talk about patterns that work sometimes vs. those that work always?

Tags: terminology, theoretical-linguistics

To say that John ate something, you say *John ate (something)*, and it's always grammatical. To talk about the state or time of filling some role, you append *-hood* or *-ship*, as in *womanhood*, but for most roles this method fails. Is there a name for this (or have I identified a salient distinction at all)?

Answer (score 7):

For affixes in particular, you can talk about how *productive* they are.  So for instance, *-er* is highly productive — you can add it to just about any verb — and *-ship* is much less productive.

Some affixes have become entirely *un*productive: for instance, we've got a few leftover plurals in *-en*, like *oxen* and *children,* but you can't coin new ones (except as a joke).

With syntactic constructions, it turns out that most are pretty productive. (Though I guess you could argue that old frozen phrases — like "hallowed be thy name" or "o'er the ramparts we watched" — represent unproductive constructions.) The restrictions you do see on syntactic constructions tend to be mostly about semantics and not grammar.  For instance, you can *persuade a person* of something, but you can't *persuade a rock* of anything.  Still, the sentence "I persuaded that rock to get out of my way" is perfectly grammatical — it's just that if you take it literally, it doesn't make any sense.